# How can I have aliases for the a package inside a package in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Suppose I have a third party package inside my Python package:

```
package/
  mymodule
  3rdparty/
    othermodule
```

Files inside the `3rdparty` package use `from 3rdparty import othermodule` (1).

However, I want to be able to also use `import package.3rdparty.othermodule` (2) from my own modules (`mymodule`).

How can I accomplish this? If I import the 3rd party package from `mymodule` using import method (2) I get a `No module named: 3rdparty` error when `othermodule` attemps to import using import method (1).

Ideally, I would not mess with the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Forgot to say, I have empty `__init__.py` files both inside `package` and `3rdparty`. However, even when adding `import package.3rdparty as 3rdparty` to the `3rdparty/__init__.py` file I still get the error.

Comment: I think not, it's just an illustrative name

Comment: Right, just it's a bit problematic to choose an illustrative name that means anyone who's answering your question with the names  you chose is typing code that's invalid syntax (so those answers couldn't be successfully tested without not just additions but also changes).

Comment: That said, I just realized I was answering a different-but-related question. For the question you're _actually_ asking, you _will_ need to either change the PYTHONPATH or its `sys.path` equivalent, or make your module tree installable (as by creating an appropriate `setup.py` and having your users use pip or similar tools).

Comment: That's a good point about the naming. Also, I did not understand your last suggestion. Where exactly should I add `import 3rdparty`?

Comment: `package/__init__.py` is where `import 3rdparty` should go, if you want someone who runs `import package` to be able to refer to `package.3rdparty`. (As I said, I was answering the wrong question for a while).

Comment: Ah yes, this is not the same as the original question. But I think you're right, I have either to change the pythonpath, make it an instalable package OR change the imports inside the `3rdparty` package. I was hoping for an easier fix.

Comment: ...to let folks run `import package.3rdparty` directly from the outside, though, you're in the space where you need to make your package installable. The best place to start there is probably the setuptools documentation.